# How to export / import keys with a pattern in redis?

Tags: redis

I am trying to carry a subset of the keys of a redis database to another remote one which is not directly accessible.

That is why I am searching for a method to export the subset of the keys (like the command `keys prefix*` gives all the keys that start with 'prefix', something like `dump prefix*`). And then carry the exported file and import into the remote server.

Existing solutions that I found are asking to dump keys individually. The method I am looking for is to export keys that match a pattern (and then import them in the remote server).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SCAN` command to iterate those keys. For each key, use the `DUMP` command to get the serialized value, and use the `RESTORE` command to write it to another Redis database.